# Create 76 out of 1,2,3,4

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

You can use +,-,*,/,^,! and sqrt operations (no concatenation) and all numbers must be used once and only once.
for example, 75 can be made by $3×(4!+2-1)$ and $81=(2-1)×3^4$

I've been trying to reach 100 and this appears to be the first impossible number.
Similar using 1 to 5, 202 appears to be the first impossible number.

Comment: For your comment about 202, you can do $202=(5*3^4-1)/2$

Comment: A refined version of my program gave solutions for the 1–5 problem for all but 6 numbers in 0–1000: 892, 917, 919, 926, 941, 942.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107527/calculation-the-hard-way Its a really nice puzzle to play with students to teach them how to do math in their head :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> I wrote [a program](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=xVXBctMwEL1x8FcsYSBSIorTAsN0mhzIL4TJIRNmnFhuNbYl15aDPZl8BwcuvcCP8Bd8DbuSXZKWQ0_QQ7pavd19eruSv_0oWntj9N3d99omrz_8esaT0uSQR_YGVF6Y0oKqbksrIIm21pQqygRk5jpwMGVlaY3Jqh67NflG6cgqoysBhSzz2vqVDzDoijBNj4_iWEBVbwTkNSZOMmPKWO0w1HwJgkzlMP1TmE1CHgQLdO2ZEqD4JSSDvToMIKGMoDSwiTgXF-ItPwRzwh3gBXEqMmllDLrON7JEKgi_JXgZ6WvJ3vPLAHGfdFS2HUPHGJYuReDSM6YFjOpKxhwZc4penOH584pROKgENFxBSDaW1FbpWqKNh5x6CZnmuNYprhkKyse2Rl7MpewTzGACkY4xajQ6h-kUXbTEIG2sq-nyL1c6XZM0g5LtqwMf-PgLuKII_Jl4Hsn2RD9HoGOQbB8xcBQeVDoq5So9H5BUH9UjrZxGkdg4ZY7HgC3EuVOoIf0wU4R21aCxWEVrtFv073C5IX_r_Ju1P1AlLas5vHLGjj_UlmqawvXdDRLOkMeUssI8pmCNaPuTkW8GOFL-XEdpvCJeixXC1uMKZ1PGrB7v-NOEaQ58PxwPCYiEsG_IB2RWSRj-_Do8IKJ1XTpR6fh6_BuV3E07uWQejUmY591vurFjLblCwATNy5ZzMjochnpIQ0NPG21vsGYWur12hA8FazjMpvRkMNSe499j_f9Pu14ftQuF6dr15sh7L4bf-nzUyOVZXcSRlWyBFelJWp5tTdEyTtdjge9KlcjyL08PzPvAfXoJOz8QqdidPihEIZOapZxovDt0NZ4YcoURQXCjLKnaaZO6sJRC5g-yu15NwpDalK7CNf3Hh_YeT4lQw6JU2jICCJiv0jX3X4zuw9F_QH4D) and it returned this:
>  $$76=4×\sqrt{(3!)!/2+1}$$

> The output (using reverse Polish notation) of a refined version of my program, capable of handling the 1–5 problem, can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Parcly-Taxel/4cb6705d2f9903a3fcb137b5e8b89ab4). Only 85, 86 and 93 are impossible for the 1–4 problem from 0 to 100, while 892, 917, 919, 926, 941 and 942 are impossible for the 1–5 problem from 0 to 1000.

Comment: Can you briefly explain how the script operates? I am very interested in it but it's very hard to read from the code as it is.

Comment: @Minot I typed the whole script on my smartphone. It is basically a depth-limited search over expressions with respect to the number of operators.

Comment: That's a very nice solution, I don't think I ever would off found that without code, onwards to 100!

Comment: @RiIgnis Wow, 9.33 * 10^157 is quite the goal!

Comment: @Iceman76 Where did that number come from?

Comment: "100 factorial"

Answer (score 4):

This is potentially not quite in the spirit of the puzzle, but how about:

> we try a little concatenation?  You said we can use "and".

> =(1&3^2) x 4 = 76
> =(1&9) x 4 = 76
> =19 x 4 = 76

Comment: Yeah, no concatenation unfortunately though would be interesting to see how high you could get if it was allowed.

Comment: If you are going to use concatenation, you may as well say 4^3 + 12, which does not require the "&" symbol ;)

Comment: @wimi - Good call!  That might count as a legit answer.  Each digit used once.  No sneaky interpretation of the operators required.

Comment: @wimi $2×(41-3)$ is simpler.

Comment: Coincidentally as I read the initial question, my brain instantly delivered "4^3" and 4^3+12 ^^