# Create number 985 using 1 3 5 7 9

Tags: formation-of-numbers

Use $1, 3, 5, 7, 9$ in any order to make number $985$:

1. You must use all $5$ digits $1, 3, 5, 7, 9$ exactly once. You can make multi-digit numbers out of the numbers, e.g. $13$ or $975$.
2. $+, -, *, /, (), \text{^}, \text{and }!$ (factorial) are the only allowed functions. Example: factorial may be used more than once, e.g. $(3!)!=720$ is acceptable.

Comment: Is the modulo function allowed? (It's used in an answer below)

Comment: Since it never says it's disallowed we must assume it is allowed. I would not advise changing the puzzle after some one came up with a good answer just because it was not the intended one.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh "Since it never says it's disallowed we must assume it is allowed" I don't think that's valid reasoning - then clearly, the constant-985 function should also be allowed! To me, rule 5 seems like an explicit list of allowed functions.

Answer (score 25):

A small modification to the program from [this answer of mine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/118711/75318) yielded this:

> $$985=(3!)!+\frac{7!-5}{19}$$

Comment: Excellent, great finding!

Answer (score 10):

Below equation should give desired result:

> $$\mod(5, 3!) * 197 = 5 * 197 = 985$$

Comment: +1 for this solution as well!

Answer (score 1):

Slightly cheeky:

> $-5-\dfrac{(-9)!}{(1-3!-7)!}$

"Justification"

> $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-n} \frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x)} = -n$

The same method allows for a variation of @Aman's answer

> $-197 \times (-5)! / (-(3!))!$

Answer (score -1):

A cheeky, but ingenious way:

> We do $7+1$ to make $8$ and then use $9$, $8$ (The number from the previous equation) and $5$ to make $985$.
>  Here's the cheeky part: We use the last digit ($3$) by doing $x = 3$. Then we can do $985 + (x - x)$ to get $985$.
>  $x = 3$ isn't a function!

Full equation ($answer$ means answer):

> $$answer = (985) + (x - x), x = 3, 1 + 7 = 8$$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community It's so clear lol